# How do I prevent .slideToggle() from 'over stacking'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var up = false;

  $('#that_list').slideUp();

  $('#updates').click(function() {
    $('#that_list').slideToggle(200);
  });

});
```

It works, but if I click the anchor called updates too many times the list of items called `that_list` slides up and down multiple times after I stop clicking. I'm pretty new to jquery and javascript and have not found a solution to this on the website (maybe I'm not searching for the right question.)

Comment: Use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the animation queue.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can move on with my life(stuck on this for a week)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666871/how-to-stop-jquery-queuing-animation-effects

Comment: @user3705223 Is that really true?

Comment: yup. I didn't know how to prevent it from glitching. I wanted to fix that before moving on to something else. I gave up and decided to finally come here and ask.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the jQuery docs, "Spend a little time now, it will save you lots of time later".