# How to run two jQuery animations on a single element simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

We can write a single line of code only if the animation functions are same, like `animate( {top: "50px", opacity: 0} )`, but how do you perform the animations simultaneously if the animation functions are different, say slide up and `animate( {top: "50px"} )`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run two jQuery animations simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2):

When calling to `.animate()` set the `queue` value to false, which will cause all animations to run at the same time.

```
$('div').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    height: '400px',
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 5000
}).animate({
    width: '500px'
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 5000
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/uRj4b/)**

Comment: basically I want to use fadeIn and animate so that the element fades into the screen as well as move mhrizontally for which I may change its left position or the margin. I cant seem to get it going... can we specify queue: false in the fadeIn effect also... if we can kindly tell the syntax as I am already using is but cannot get it to work....

Comment: Simply use `.animate()` instead of `fadeIn()` e.g. `.animate({  "opacity": "show"},{queue:false, duration:"slow"});`