# jQuery: Calling 2 functions same time?

Tags: jquery, animation, sequence

Can I call 2 functions at the same time with jQuery?

For example:

I am trying to perform something like http://www.wunderkit.com/. If you notice, when the sofa fade's In, it animates down at the same second. When it moves at the very end bottom it comes up for around 3-4 pixels.

Currently I have:

```
$(".logo").fadeIn().animate({ marginTop: 20 }, 'fast', function() {                         
        $(this).animate({ marginTop: -5 }, '');
});
```

This fade's In the logo, waits 1-2 seconds and then the animation begins.

Is there any other way I can call this?

Thanks alot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

> if a `queue: false` flag is included in the options of animate(), then
>   that animation will not go in the queue and will begin running
>   immediately.

from [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Effects#Simultaneous_Animations)

see if this does what you're looking for:

```
$(function () {
    $(".logo").fadeIn().animate({ marginTop: 20 }, { queue: false }, 'fast');
    $(".logo").fadeIn().animate({ marginTop: -5 }, { queue: false }, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in more than one option to `.animate()`, that is the whole point.

```
  $('#logo').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    marginTop: '20',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 'fast', function() {
    $(this).animate({ marginTop: -5 }, '');
  });
```

This will do the fade and scroll at the same time.