# jQuery Animate - Apply 2 different animation attributes to the same element with 2 different timers

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The jQuery below works great, but I'd like to have the opacity last 2000 and the marginLeft 4000. I tried doing animate twice on the element but one wont start until the other has completed. Here is my working code:

```
$('.active-text', $('#message-box')).animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "60px"}, 4000);
```

Here is what i tried doing to get the desired affect:

```
$('.active-text', $('#message-box')).animate({opacity:1}, 2000);
$('.active-text', $('#message-box')).animate({marginLeft: "60px"}, 4000);
```

Comment: You can check this answer (possible duplicate):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `queue: false` in your animations to run it both at the same time:

```
$('.active-text', $('#message-box')).animate({opacity:1}, { queue: false, duration: 2000 });
$('.active-text', $('#message-box')).animate({marginLeft: "60px"}, { queue: false, duration: 4000 });
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! I simplified it abit like this: $('.active-text', $('#message-box')).animate({opacity:1}, { queue: false, duration: 1000 }).animate({marginLeft: "60px"}, { queue: false, duration: 4000 });