# jquery scale using animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to use the transform "scale" for a DIV using Jquery's animate function but it is not showing any effect.
Can someone tell if "transforms" are supported in Jquery's animate function.
I also tried JQuery's UI/Effect "scale" method but as I am not sure if it is supported as it is throwing aan error that the "property" is not supported by the object.
Might be possibly because I am using it on a metro app.

Comment: maybe this topic can help you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118358/jquery-scale-and-fade-at-the-same-time/11118619

Answer (score 1):

include this file in ur code

```
 jquery.transform2d.js
```

and then use the animate function to scale div

```
$("div").animate({"transform" : "scale(2)"});
```

Comment: thanks.can you tell me where can I find the transform2d plugin.It seems that Jquery plugin site is going reconstruction.

Comment: This js is available here https://gist.github.com/MhdAljuboori/6cbce2a3efa897f6f8e7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Transit plugin for css transformations
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Jquery animate function only accepts those properties having numerical values.

Read this for more details http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

This should help.