# jquery animated txt color change of two different divs at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have two divs with the same class, I'd like to animate them to a different color at the same time, but when I do this one animates and finishes, and only then does the other change.  Is there a way to make them do this at the same time?  Right now I'm doing it like so:

```
  $('.menutxt').animate({color:"#333333"},400);
  $('#burlington_txt').animate({color:"#ffffff"},400);
```

both have the class menutxt.

Thanks for any help I can get on this.

Comment: yup that's it, if you wanna post it as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks for pointing me to that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously), you can do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#first").animate({
       width: '200px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#second").animate({
       width: '600px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
});
```

**EDIT**: For your code, it would be:

```
$('.menutxt').animate({
  color:"#333333"
}, {
  duration: 400,
  queue: false
});
$('#burlington_txt').animate({
  color:"#ffffff"
}, {
  duration: 400,
  queue: false
});
```