# 50% / 50% divs, on click 100% animation

Tags: jquery

**What am I doing:**

I am working on a website with 2 different "sides", when you click on the left side, the left side need to be 100%. If you click on the right side, the right side has to be 100%.

**Done already:**

I have made the left and right side. And animated it with Jquery.

**Problem**
When you click on the left div the animation is working (It only worked when I added position absolute), but when I try to create the same animation for the right side; it isn't working! I created a jsFiddle so you can see the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/

I can't make the right one work. When you click on the right div; it need to animate to 100%. Just like the left one.

**Code**

You can see a live preview and code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$('#left').click(function(){
    $('#left').animate({width:'100%'}, 2500);
});
</script>
<script>
$('#right').click(function(){
    $('#right').animate({width:'100%'}, 2500);
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
p { 
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
#left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #666;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #063;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me.
Regards,
Milan

PS: If I posted/did something wrong in this topic; I'm sorry, this is my first question.

Comment: Try to put position:absolute to the right div too!

Comment: You're using jsfiddle wrong, include all external libraries from the panel on the left, also you have a syntax error <div id="left" onclick=></div>

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix is straight away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a small work around. I have edited your fiddle Please check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/4/

```
$('#left').animate({width:'0%'}, 2500);
$('#right').animate({width:'100%'}, 2500);
```

Hope the code is clear to you. Please feel free in case of any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I have one bug; When I click on a div, the other one is "pushed" out of the screen (to the button)

Comment: consider this one then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously

Comment: @ElegantCoder : When I try this code in 3 different browsers; chrome, ff and safari. I have one problem; When the animation takes place the other div is "pushed" to the bottom.

Comment: @Milan I have done some work around. Please check the new fiddle. [JSfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/21/)

Comment: @Milan : You are welcome. I hope you understood why the part was pushing down.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#right` grows to 100%, but it grows under the `#left`

You should place `#right` above the left container using a positioning other than `static`.

So the magic is:

- Use absolute or fixed positioning
- On click, change the `z-index` of the active element to be greater than the `z-index` of the other

```
#left, #right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
#left {
    left:0;
    background: #666;
}
#right {
    background: #063;
    right: 0;
}
```

And the script:

```
var Z = 0;
$('#left').click(function(){
    $('#left').css('z-index',Z++).animate({width:'100%'}, 2500);
});




$('#right').click(function(){
    $('#right').css('z-index',Z++).animate({width:'100%'}, 2500);
});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/19/

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/20/)**</kbd>

HTML: (add a specific class:)

```
<div id="left" class="toggWidth"></div>
<div id="right" class="toggWidth"></div>
```

jQ:

```
$('.toggWidth').click(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width:'100%'}, 2500)
           .siblings('.toggWidth').stop().animate({width:'0%'}, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it is working. But I'll use the other code (Just because I understand the other one better) Still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is correct. But why you are doing `width:100%` ? As i clicked a div it got 100% and then i can't get back to previous state. I tried it with `width:95%`

You can have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/24/

Comment: One would think the OP has thought of that and has a mechanism for reverting.

Comment: hmm... i was just thought to make it user friendly :)

Comment: I was thinking of a "back" button; but this is also a nice idea. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is that the left div is set to 50% before the right so it has predominance.

it's exactly like setting left to 50% and right to 100%, it will be exactly as if you had set both to 50%

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess around with `width` and `height`, you can do this all with positioning.

The missing bit in your example was `z-index`, as one div was disappearing below the other.

Here's my [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Rg/22/).

HTML:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
#left {
    background: #666;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}
#right {
    background: #063;
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css('z-index', 1);
    if (this.id === 'right') {
        $(this).animate({left: 0}, 2500);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({right: 0}, 2500);
    }
});
```