# jquery CSS properties selecting

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create something when clicking on the image inside the `div` element. It should change it's color to blue, alongside changing the background color to blue. Is the code I am writing correct? Because it's not working properly. Also, is there a better way to apply CSS to elements?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fagc9/)

```
var photo = $('#photo');
var html = $('html');
var bg = $('#bg');
$(photo).on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide()
  .delay(600)
  .fadeIn(300);
  $(html, bg).css({
    background :'blue'
  });
});
```

**html**

```
<div id='bg'>
    <img id='photo' src="http://img.pixland.uz/u11878f337693s.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run two jQuery animations simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously)

Comment: see this working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Fagc9/1/

Comment: @ShekharPankaj Not working!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using photo as jquery object so no need to use a `$` for photo again, or try it like,

```
var photo = '#photo';
var html = 'html';
var bg = '#bg';
$(photo).on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide()
    .delay(600)
    .fadeIn(300);
    $(html+','+ bg).css({
    // to make multiple selectors into a single one
        background :'blue'
    });
});
```

Refer [multiple-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for more details

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fagc9/2/)

Comment: thank you @Rohan Kumar this is what i needed people did not understand me. `thank you`

Comment: `$(html+','+ bg)`? I would prefer `html.add(bg)` or `bg.add(html)`

Answer (score 3):

As well as [Rohan Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23855140/417562), which is of course wholly correct, there is a method for combining jQuery selections: [`$.fn.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/). You can pass an HTML element, an array of elements, a jQuery selection, a jQuery selector or an HTML string to it. In this case, we could pass one of the jQuery objects you created:

In this case you could do the selection with `html.add(bg)`:

```
var photo = $('#photo');
var html = $('html');
var bg = $('#bg');
photo.on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide()
  .delay(600)
  .fadeIn(300);
  html.add(bg).css({
    background :'blue'
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fagc9/3/)