# My slide in / out animation is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the site:

```
kotechweb.com/new_focus/page/proposal
```

Please notice that in left corner there is a menu button, I would like the button to slide and hide the menu if menu is open, on the other hand, if the menu is closed, slide in the button and show the menu.

The code is

```js
var is_closed = false;

$("#menu_btn").on("click", function () {
    if (is_closed) {
        $("#menu_right ul").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
        $(this).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
    } else {
        $("#menu_right ul").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
        $(this).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
    }
    is_closed = !is_closed;
});
```

However, right now the menu_btn is not animated properly; it does not slide, but only hides.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The `show()` and `hide()` methods that you've implemented in fact belong to jQuery UI (and NOT jQuery).*

Since jQuery's built-in `show()` and `hide()` don't support special effects, to get round your problem, I reproduced roughly the same situation using jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/e8pfkn8o/).

The following sums it all up:

1. Calculate the width of `#menu_right ul`, say in a variable `slideSpan`.
2. Set the `left` property of both the `#menu_right ul` and `#menu_btn` to as much as the `slideSpan` while closing, and to `0` when opening it back:

   ```
   //while closing
   $(this).siblings('#menu_right ul').animate({left: -slideSpan}, 1000, 'swing');
   $(this).animate({left: -slideSpan}, 1000, 'swing');

   // ...
   // while opening
   $(this).siblings('#menu_right ul').animate({left: 0}, 1000, 'swing');
   $(this).animate({left: 0}, 1000, 'swing');
   ```

**Note:** For the `animate()` to function properly, make sure that the `#menu_right`, `#menu_right ul`, and `#menu_btn` have their CSS positions set (to relative), and that the `#menu_right ul` and `#menu_btn` are *floating* to left.

*Animations created via `animate()` run simultaneously, due to the `queue` property of the method defaulting to `false`.*

Comment: Actually they're in JQuery

Comment: But the ones in jQuery and jQuery UI are quite different. Check [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/show/) out.

Comment: Ohhh, you're right. My mistake. I usually end up using both and misremembered.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is that the two animations are done at the same time?
Adding 'queue: false' (warning: untested code):

```
$("#menu_right ul").show("slide", {direction: "left", queue: false}, 1000);
$(this).show("slide", {direction: "left", queue: false}, 1000);
```

Copied from this question:
[How to run two jQuery animations simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously)

Comment: ok, I see that the command applied to #menu_right ul is 'show' and 'hide', and the command applied to the button is 'show' and 'show' is that correct? just checking.