# When to use jQuery animation promises instead of the callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following query. **When to use this:**

```
$('#box').hide(2000).promise().done(function(){
     $('#output').text('Box is hidden');
});
```

**instead of this:**

```
$('#box').hide(2000,function(){
     $('#output').text('Box is hidden');
});
```

***What are some useful scenarios for using the `.promise()` method with jQuery animations?***

Thank you

Comment: For this situation, there aren't any. Promises are useful [for more complicated cases](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970).

Comment: I find that Promises are most used for returning the response for an XHR request, or any other async event.

Comment: Please re-open this question.  Folks, answers to this do not have to be primarily opinion-based at all.  There are good supporting facts why one is better than the other.  Read the answer provided.  It's not primarily opinion.  Try writing a function to coordinate four different timed async operations without using promises.  It's a ton more code.  Anyone who knows how to use promises will understand how it is a simpler design using promises.

Comment: @jfriend00: I didn't vote to close, however, as asked the question is primarily opinion based.  It doesn't ask about coordination of multiple animations at all.

Comment: @SamAxe - The meaning of the question is why one would use promises with animations.  The answer is to use them when you have multiple things to coordinate.  That's not primarily an opinion.  It's easily shown with facts and examples. Folks here are way, way too quick to close some because it COULD have an opinion-based answer when perfectly good non-opinion-based answers are always possible.  If someone supplies an answer that is not primarily opinion, the question should not be closed.  This rule was put in place to prevent opinion-debates.  There is little danger of that here.

Comment: Please remember that a question should ONLY be voted closed for opinion if in the words of the FAQ and close vote description: ***"answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise"***.  You don't vote to close just because the question could be answered with an opinion, only if that's really the **only** way it could be answered.

Comment: @jfriend00: I absolutely agree with most of your little rant.  The part that I (and apparently others) disagree with is that **AS ASKED** the question is about the OP's specific example code.  The question needs to be modified to be more general for it to be non-opinion based.

Comment: @SamAxe - If people want to be literal, then it's easy to be picky, but one can also clearly see what the OP is after here and an answer with value to both the OP and the community can be had (that's the definition of a question that should remain in my mind, particularly when such an answer has already been posted).  The OP asks in bold: **Can you give me some good reasons for using promises?** and the context for that is the `.promise()` method.  That's what I answered.  I'll attempt to edit the question a bit.

Comment: Question edited to focus it a bit more on the jQuery `.promise()` method.

Comment: @jfriend00: It's unclear why you are so invested in this particular question... it wasn't asked by you... but... Programming is all about being literal.  The question, as asked - with context, does not immediately suggest that the OP is looking for the use of promises in a broader context.  The context suggests they have a very narrow (opinion-based) focus to their question.   Arguing for the salvation of a poorly crafted question doesn't do anyone any favors.   *You gave a very well worded, well thought-out answer.  I upvoted it.  But a good answer doesn't justify not closing a bad question.*

Comment: Meta seems like a good place for this.  When you post on there put the link here.  I'm sure many people will be happy to flood the thread with their opinions. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're just animating one item, there is little reason to use a promise over a direct callback.  In this particular case, promises are more useful when you're trying to coordinate multiple different async operations (which is where promises are generally the most useful).

Suppose you had a whole bunch of items you were hiding and you wanted ONE callback when they were all done.  Then, this would do exactly that:

```
$('.items, .boxes').hide(2000).promise().then(function(){
     $('#output').text('All hidden');
});
```

Or, suppose you wanted to know when multiple different animations were done so you needed to coordinate multiple actions.  Promises have built-in features for that which are more work to hand-code without promises:

```
var p1 = $('.items, .boxes').hide(2000).promise();
var p2 = $('.sliders').slideUp(2500).promise();
var p3 = $('.openers').slideDown(1500).promise();
$.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function() {
    // all are done here
});
```

If you want to hand code that without promises, then you will have to maintain a counter and, in each separate callback, check the counter to see if they are all done.  It's a lot more code.  Now, if you there are then errors to deal with or multiple other operations chained onto this, any option without callbacks or without some async supporting library quickly becomes a real pain to hand code.  That is why promises were invented.

Or, even extend beyond an animation, imagine you want to coordinate both an animation and an ajax call (which you have no idea how long it will take):

```
var p1 = $('.items, .boxes').hide(2000).promise();
var p2 = $.ajax(...);
$.when(p1, p2).then(function() {
    // both are done here
});
```

---

Here's a demo of the differences in notifications.  If you press "Reset", then press "Callbacks", you will see that you get 5 completion notifications.  If you press "Reset" and then press "Promises", you will see that you get 1 completion notification when they are all done.

```js
// configure logging
log.id = "results";

$("#runPromises").click(function() {
  $('.items, .boxes').hide(2000).promise().then(function(){
       log("got done notification")
  });
});
$("#runCallbacks").click(function() {
  $('.items, .boxes').hide(2000, function(){
       log("got done notification")
  });
});

$("#reset").click(function() {
  $(".items, .boxes").show();
  $("#results").empty();
});
```

```css
.items {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.boxes {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#results {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://files.the-friend-family.com/log.js"></script>
<button id="runCallbacks">Callbacks</button> 
<button id="runPromises">Promises</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="boxes"></div>
  <div class="boxes"></div>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Does `$.ajax()` create a promise automatically, or would you need to adjust the last example to be `var p2 = $.ajax(...).promise();` ?

Comment: @SamAxe - `$.ajax()` already returns a promise.  You have to use `.promise()` with animations because the default for all animations functions is to return the jQuery object so you could chain jQuery operations like $("#box").slideUp().slideDown()`, so if you want a promise, you have to ask for one with `.promise()` for animations.

Comment: Thank you.  That's helpful to know.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much. It was not my intention of provoking this upheaval. Of course, my query was not just about animations; it is concerning in general about promises and their use...

Comment: @ILIAS - If you want more info about when to use promises in general or what promises are best used for or even why to use promises, there are literally hundreds of very good articles on that topic you can find with Google.  The answer in a crux is coordinating multiple asynchronous operations and easier more robust error handling particularly when there's more than one async operation involved.

Comment: One remark about the above question of @SamAxe. $.ajax() does not create a promise, it returns a jqXHR object. It is $.ajax().promise() that returns a promise object!

Comment: @ILIAS - The jqXHR object has full promise functionality and can be used directly as a promise.  I've never found a reason to use `.promise()` on a jqXHR object because the jqXHR object has the `.then()` method built right in so it can be used directlly just like a promise can.

Comment: This "promise()" saved my day! Thanks.