# How to set common speed for the toggle screen in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery for a split screen design.
The left and right panel will be visible in the split mode.
I have attached a fiddle of code that I am using for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/qEjXj/3720/

I am doing this toggle click

```
$(".slidingDiv").toggle("slide", {direction: "right" }, 1000);
$(".userDiv").toggleClass("col-12 col-6",1000);
```

The problem is that the left side goes in and then the right side screen appears.
I want is they should both appear in sync. I tried by changing the time but I am not able to get a solution.
What will be the correct approach to do this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251300/how-to-run-two-jquery-animations-simultaneously) post

Comment: @AbSin   Can "queue: false" be used with toggle or do I have to change with animate?

Comment: `$(".slidingDiv").toggle("slide", {direction: "right" }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });`. It does work with toggle, however I wasn't able to fully solve your problem.